# What does a star on a spherical harmonic mean?

Tags: notation, complex-numbers, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

So I was studying multipole expansion and the book I am using introduced spherical harmonics. While I could understand the concept of the functions themselves, the book suddenly started putting a “ * “ on the harmonic functions. The book does not mention this previously, and a wiki search didn’t help either.
Can someone explain what the “ * “ means in context of spherical harmonics?

Comment: It would help a lot more of you mentioned what book you are using.

Comment: “The Classical Electromagnetic Field” by Leonard Eyges

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with spherical harmonics in particular, an asterisk is one of the common notations for the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

Comment: Now I’m confused. How do complex conjugates come in multipole expansion?

Comment: The spherical harmonics are in general complex valued functions, so it makes sense if you want to say define orthogonality and normalization conditions it requires the definition of an inner product of harmonics through $\iint Y_{\ell}^m Y_{\ell '}^{m' *} d \Omega$